# Making Tomcat log in /var/log

Tags: logging, tomcat, java, path

I'm trying to make our Tomcat 9 server log its internal log in `/var/log` instead of `${catalina.base}/logs`.

I tried to change the destinations in logging.properties, but the logs directory in `${catalina.base}` is actually a symbolic link, so changing the destination to `/var/log` should do the trick. None of both ideas worked.

Also, I'm wondering if it could be caused by `catalina.policy`, but that would mean Tomcat being launched with the `-secure` option. My Tomcat is started as service using systemd. I have no idea how I could check if -secure is used or not.

The Tomcat's `logging.properties` is actually used. When I check the process with `ps`, I get `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/rh/jws5/root/usr/share/tomcat/conf/logging.properties`, which is the right file, the one I tried to modify.

I'm using Tomcat 9 with Java 8 on RHEL 8.

**Edit**: I also tried to add `ReadWritePaths=/var/log/tomcat` or `ReadWritePaths=/var/log` in the service file. Still no change.

**Edit2**: Some details on the current configuration. My CATALINA_BASE is  /opt/rh/jws5/root/usr/share/tomcat. It contains the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 134 Dec  7 16:18 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  28 Nov 15 17:45 conf -> /etc/opt/rh/scls/jws5/tomcat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Nov 15 17:45 lib -> /opt/rh/jws5/root/usr/share/java/tomcat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jan 31 17:42 logs -> /var/log/tomcat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Nov 15 17:45 temp -> /var/opt/rh/scls/jws5/cache/tomcat/temp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  40 Nov 15 17:45 webapps -> /var/opt/rh/scls/jws5/lib/tomcat/webapps
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Nov 15 17:45 work -> /var/opt/rh/scls/jws5/cache/tomcat/work
```

logs previously pointed to /var/opt/rh/scls/jws5/log/tomcat. With the current configuration, Tomcat is not logging in /var/opt/rh/scls/jws5/log/tomcat anymore. But it doesn't log in /var/log either.

Here the snippet of my logging.properties file with the various paths:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8
```

**Edit3**: I tried to replace those `${catalina.base}/logs` in the `logging.properties` by `/var/log/tomcat`, still to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally solved the issue consists in 2 points:

- My Tomcat process doesn't belong to  root, so the /var/log/tomcat directory need read/write rights for everybody.
- The following lines need to be added to the `grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" {` section of the `catalina.policy` file:

  ```
   permission java.io.FilePermission
    "/var/log/tomcat", "read, write";
   permission java.io.FilePermission
    "/var/log/tomcat/*", "read, write, delete";
  ```